# Как изменить false на true при переключении в настройках?

Tags: android, android-preferences

В активити webview прописано:

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Как при переключении кнопки в настройках сменить true на false?

Саму кнопку я уже обозначил:

```
<SwitchPreference
        android:key="switchJS"
        android:summary="@string/setting_JS_des"
        android:title="@string/setting_JS_title"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно как то так это все выглядит. При переходе в настройки и при переключении там свитча его текущее значение автоматически сохраняется в преференсы. При возврате из настроек мы читаем это значение из преференсов и присваиваем када на нужно. Проделываем эти операции в `onResume()`, так как при переходе в настройки активити не уничтожается и метод `onCreate()` при возврате вызван не будет:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

   private SharedPreferences mPreference;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    }  

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        boolean isEnableJS = mPreference.getBoolean("swithJS", true);
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(isEnabledJS);
    }
}
```